# Pause JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I need to pause a JavaScript function execution in the middle and then resume it after a button click. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

Break the function up in to two parts, run one, and have the other assigned to the click event handler of the button.

Comment: actually my requirement is to implement light box for window.confirm, as the window.confirm can pause the function and return true or false I would like to implement the same

Comment: @kumar, It's pretty much the same procedure as @David Dorward described, except instead of assigning a click handler, you're adding a callback to the dialog.

Comment: but I have to return true or false from the current javascript function on click of the light box yes or no buttons..

Comment: @kumar, You can pass `true` or `false` as an argument to the callback.

Comment: @kumar: You can't write a linear program in an event driven programming language when you need to deal with a user event in the middle of it. You need to rethink your program structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pop up box.

```
alert("Pausing to get Coffee");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I need to implement customized window.cofirm I am showing a light box in the mean time the function is not pausing its execution, I would like to set a hidden variable in html to true or false on click of yes or no on light boxes, and on resume of the function I will read the variable and do necessary action.

Answer (score 1):

Like David said, it is not possible to stop execution of a function in Javascript (well, not at the moment anyway). One solution would be this :

** **EDITED** ** after you added some precision to what you wanted to do

```
// pass the reference of the button id to the function
function showConfirm(message, callback) {
   // 1. check if the lightbox is not already created, if not create it
   // 2. keep a reference to your key elements, for example, your buttons
   var btnOk = document.getElementById('btnOk');  // ...for example
   var btnCancel = document.getElementById('btnCancel');  // ...for example

   // 3. have a 'cleanup' function so you can dismiss your lightbox, unregister
   //      any events/callbacks, etc.
   var cleanup = function() {
      // 6. hide lightbox
      // 7. remove events/callbacks, etc.
      btnOk.click = null;  // for example
      btnCancel.click = null; // for example

      // etc.
   };


   // 4. update your lightbox with the message given in argument

   // 5. register some events to your buttons...
   btnOk.click = function() {
      callback(true);  // ok was pressed
      cleanup();
   };
   btnCancel.click = function() {
      callback(false); // cancel was pressed
      cleanup();
   }

}
```

All you have to remember is that, in Javascript, everything should be asynchronous. If your function should return a value, it should be a function that does not require long to execute. As soon as you read "user input" with Javascript, you *need* callbacks. You might want to take a look at how other lightbox implementations are done, especially in frameworks like JQuery, etc.